# Calculate Compound limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I am in great difficulty to calculate this limit. $$\lim_{x\to0}(\cos x) \frac{1}{x\sin(2x)}$$
I know that the $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \cos x=0$, and the fraction it will be $\frac{1}{0}$ but it doesn't exist. So I don't know how to solve it, what kind of mistake am I making. Is here someone who may explain it to me, or tell me what rules I have to watch? Also, I have tied Comparison theorem, but it will be $- 1/1\leq x\sin x(2x)\leq 1/1$ and this is also incorrect.

Comment: It is $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x)=1$

Comment: what do you understand  with lim x->0 (cos(x)) cos(x)->0 so x->pi/2?

Comment: The limit is of the form $\frac10$, so it doesn't exist.  Why is that a problem?

Comment: @saulspatz nope. It's moltiplicate. (COSX) (1/xsinx(2x))

Comment: Wait! Are you suggesting that $$\cos{x}\cdot{1\over x\sin{2x}}\neq{\cos{x}\over x\sin{2x}}?$$

Comment: @saulspatz I updated the code. You can see above. Now it's correct

Comment: How is that any different?  Look at my last comment.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I meant that (cos x) must multiply the fraction

Comment: Do you not know that $a\left({1\over b}\right)={a\over b}$?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I know that. Sorry I was using mobile app, and I didn't see well what you wrote to me, I just see the code. I think that I solved it, because cos x=1, and x sin (2x)=0. So I must to calculate right limit and left limit. But I see that |x^2| it1s always positive. So the limit =+∞. I think it's correct.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I'm glad you explained what was going on; I was getting worried.

Answer (score 2):

Write $$\frac{\cos(x)}{x\cdot 2\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$

Comment: I can't understand how you get x*2sin(x)cos(x)? Cos I try to solve it again, and I have cos(x)(x sin (2x)) and it will be 0*0. So at the end I have 1/0=doesnt exist.

Comment: It is $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x\sim x$ in the process $x\to 0$, thus
$$\lim _{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x}{x\sin 2x} = \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2x\sin x} = \lim _{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2x^2} = +\infty. $$

Answer (score 1):

For small enough $|x|$ we have $$x\sin 2x<2x^2$$therefore $${\cos x\over x\sin 2x}>{{1\over 2}\over 2x^2}={1\over 4x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of this problem I'm going to assume that $cos(x)$ is defined as the standard cosine function with $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\cos(x)$=1 and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<\cos(x)<1$ for $x\in[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$. I will also assume that $\sin(x)$ is defined as the standard sine function with $\sin(x)=-\sin(-x)$ and $0\leq\sin(x)\leq1$ for $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\sin(0)=0$.

I contend that for any $\epsilon$ you give me I can find a $\delta$ such that $$|x|<\delta \implies \frac{\cos(x)}{x \sin(2x)}>\epsilon.$$

We know that for $\delta <\pi/4$:

1. $\frac{\cos(x)}{x \sin(2x)} > 0$ since $\cos(x)>0$ and since sign($x$) = sign($\sin(2x)$) then $x\sin(2x)>0$
2. $\frac{\cos(x)}{x \sin(2x)}>\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{2}}$

Therefore choose $\delta = \min(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\epsilon})$

This establishes that the limit increases without stop as $x$ approaches 0.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\cos x=\color{red}1?$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I did. Thank you for spotting that

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way (1)/( x sin x(2x))=1/0= ∞. So I'm going to calculate right and left limit and I have + ∞ and -  ∞. But if I'm looking that (1) /(2x^2(sin x) /x) =1/2x^2=+∞